# Desktop CPU run then stop after 1 or 2 seconds

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

I'm having an issue with my desktop computer every time I try to run it. It just start happening couple two weeks ago. So what's actually happening is that when I'm trying to run it and press the start button, all the CPU fans will start to spin, then after 1 or 2 seconds, it will automatically stop. When I try to press the start button again, nothing will be going happen like it's dead. I will have to remove the the power cord and put it back again to make it run again and the same scenario will happen again and again until it will luckily boot into BIOS and OS. I'm literally spending hours doing this (removing the power cord, putting it back, then pressing the start button) to make it boot to my OS.

At first, I thought it was a problem with my PSU, so I bought a new one and replaced the old one, but the same issue is still happening. I already tried removing all the hardwares and cleaning all the slots but no luck.

I have MSI Military Class 4 A55M-E35 motherboard

[image]

```
Processor: AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G 3.10 GHz
Installed RAM: 16.0 GB (14.9 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition: Windows 11 Pro
Version: 22H2
Installed on: 7/‎3/‎2023
OS build: 22621.1992
```

Does anyone here have an idea what should be the problem? Looking forward and thankful for any help! Thanks!

Comment: CPU at 59 degrees in the BIOS ... perhaps it's an overheating issue

Comment: CPU's are designed to get that hot, but perhaps not that hot if you took that reading while the machine was running idle. You could try removing the CPU and clean off the thermal paste with isopropyl alcohol, and then reseat the CPU with fresh thermal paste applied beforehand. It's a bit time consuming but thermal paste is very cheap to buy. Also, have you tried updating the BIOS to the latest version?

Comment: This ^^^ and resetting it once in a while at least. And keep in mind your hardware isn't compatible with the OS version you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to give an update regarding this issue: It was the Motherboard.

As I mentioned in my first post, I've already done all the basic troubleshooting (removing all the hardware, RAM, Graphic Card, Processor, all the pins from PSU, etc) and cleaned all the slots.

I read somewhere to remove also the motherboard from the CPU Case because it might be something like loose screws that might cause groundings or something. So I did the suggestion and take a good look at all the pins (which I can't do when the MOBO is attached to the case) and noticed a small corrosion/burn at the back of the motherboard which I think is the main cause of my issue (Just my theory). So I go the nearest repair shop to test a new MOBO and after switching all my hardware, it boots to my OS without any problem.

Thanks anyway guys for all your input and suggestions! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it could be bad sectors on your hard drive.

I would use Media Creation Tool from Microsoft to make a bootable USB.

Boot from it, when you get to the main screen SHIFT F10 should get you a dos command prompt.

From there you will want to do a chkdsk /r on your main c: drive, but it will likely have some other drive letter in this environment.

[image: diskpart list volume]

You will likely want the largest one, and it should be **boot** and not **SYSTEM**.

chkdsk /r c:

Now you will have to wait hours, best if you launch it before going to work or bed.

Comment: I fail to see how a corrupt disk would intermittently prevent a system from POSTing.

Comment: from the OP "When I try to press the start button again, nothing will be going happen like it's dead."  The system freezing like this could be bad sectors.